# Need help in designing modifying UI using flutter

Tags: flutter

I am a noob in flutter. I got this sample UI from [github](https://github.com/mitesh77/Best-Flutter-UI-Templates).  This is the default home screen:

[image: Actual Home Screen].

Clicking on any of the 3 boxes renders the specific UI type. I want the home screen of anyone of the 3 UI to be the actual Home Screen for my app. For ex:

[image: Required Home Screen].

I tried to understand the code but being a noob failed to understand what needs to be done to achieve the required.

Here is the home_screen.dart file:

```
import 'package:best_flutter_ui_templates/app_theme.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'model/homelist.dart';

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  List<HomeList> homeList = HomeList.homeList;
  AnimationController animationController;
  bool multiple = true;

  @override
  void initState() {
    animationController = AnimationController(
        duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 2000), vsync: this);
    super.initState();
  }

  Future<bool> getData() async {
    await Future<dynamic>.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 0));
    return true;
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    animationController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: AppTheme.white,
      body: FutureBuilder<bool>(
        future: getData(),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<bool> snapshot) {
          if (!snapshot.hasData) {
            return const SizedBox();
          } else {
            return Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: MediaQuery.of(context).padding.top),
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: <Widget>[
                  appBar(),
                  Expanded(
                    child: FutureBuilder<bool>(
                      future: getData(),
                      builder:
                          (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<bool> snapshot) {
                        if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                          return const SizedBox();
                        } else {
                          return GridView(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                top: 0, left: 12, right: 12),
                            physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                            scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                            children: List<Widget>.generate(
                              homeList.length,
                              (int index) {
                                final int count = homeList.length;
                                final Animation<double> animation =
                                    Tween<double>(begin: 0.0, end: 1.0).animate(
                                  CurvedAnimation(
                                    parent: animationController,
                                    curve: Interval((1 / count) * index, 1.0,
                                        curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn),
                                  ),
                                );
                                animationController.forward();
                                return HomeListView(
                                  animation: animation,
                                  animationController: animationController,
                                  listData: homeList[index],
                                  callBack: () {
                                    Navigator.push<dynamic>(
                                      context,
                                      MaterialPageRoute<dynamic>(
                                        builder: (BuildContext context) =>
                                            homeList[index].navigateScreen,
                                      ),
                                    );
                                  },
                                );
                              },
                            ),
                            gridDelegate:
                                SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                              crossAxisCount: multiple ? 2 : 1,
                              mainAxisSpacing: 12.0,
                              crossAxisSpacing: 12.0,
                              childAspectRatio: 1.5,
                            ),
                          );
                        }
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            );
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget appBar() {
    return SizedBox(
      height: AppBar().preferredSize.height,
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8, left: 8),
            child: Container(
              width: AppBar().preferredSize.height - 8,
              height: AppBar().preferredSize.height - 8,
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Center(
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 4),
                child: Text(
                  'Flutter UI',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 22,
                    color: AppTheme.darkText,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8, right: 8),
            child: Container(
              width: AppBar().preferredSize.height - 8,
              height: AppBar().preferredSize.height - 8,
              color: Colors.white,
              child: Material(
                color: Colors.transparent,
                child: InkWell(
                  borderRadius:
                      BorderRadius.circular(AppBar().preferredSize.height),
                  child: Icon(
                    multiple ? Icons.dashboard : Icons.view_agenda,
                    color: AppTheme.dark_grey,
                  ),
                  onTap: () {
                    setState(() {
                      multiple = !multiple;
                    });
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class HomeListView extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomeListView(
      {Key key,
      this.listData,
      this.callBack,
      this.animationController,
      this.animation})
      : super(key: key);

  final HomeList listData;
  final VoidCallback callBack;
  final AnimationController animationController;
  final Animation<dynamic> animation;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AnimatedBuilder(
      animation: animationController,
      builder: (BuildContext context, Widget child) {
        return FadeTransition(
          opacity: animation,
          child: Transform(
            transform: Matrix4.translationValues(
                0.0, 50 * (1.0 - animation.value), 0.0),
            child: AspectRatio(
              aspectRatio: 1.5,
              child: ClipRRect(
                borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(4.0)),
                child: Stack(
                  alignment: AlignmentDirectional.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Image.asset(
                      listData.imagePath,
                      fit: BoxFit.cover,
                    ),
                    Material(
                      color: Colors.transparent,
                      child: InkWell(
                        splashColor: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.2),
                        borderRadius:
                            const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(4.0)),
                        onTap: () {
                          callBack();
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

The `HomeList.homeList` list passes the 3 different UI designs. Basically `homeList[index].navigateScreen` is what I need as the body of my Scaffold without disturbing the other widgets.

Can anybody please help me in figuring out what needs to be returned by `MyHomePage` so that instead of small boxes of the UIs, I get a particular UI as my home screen.

Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open **navigation_home_screen.dart** in **lib** project folder, you will see

```dart
  @override
  void initState() {
    drawerIndex = DrawerIndex.HOME;
    screenView = const MyHomePage();
    super.initState();
  }
```

This is where the magic happends, to put in simple, all you need is to set one of the homepages you need, import them by pressing right button -> *import ...* and delete `const` keyword:

```dart
  @override
  void initState() {
    drawerIndex = DrawerIndex.HOME;
    screenView =
        HotelHomeScreen(); // or FitnessAppHomeScreen() or DesignCourseHomeScreen()
    super.initState();
  }
```

save and restart project emulator to see changes.